# Obtaining settings based on localization

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a settings.cs file where I am giving some default settings as per country

Eg : USA – ZipFormat 
Brazil – TimeZone… etc

When I am using this application in india , I should not get these settings for me

Q. How we can implement this logic ( based on country the settings has to be applied / validated ) 
What is the best way of abstraction

Comment: First of all, what have you tried so far? Second i'd recommend to create localizable resource files for each Country-Code you want support. Example see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response lokusking :) , I was trying to find an alternative solution without resource file ,which can give some level of abstraction as well

Comment: Another solution might be [Satelite Assemblies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/global_developer/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies/). Their origin are Windows Forms but the way it works might suit your needs as you can implement your deired level of abstraction